# How to remove lookup & share from textview in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitextview

I can remove cut, copy, paste, select, select all using this

```
override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(copy(_:)) || action == #selector(paste(_:)) || action == #selector(selectAll(_:)) || action == #selector(cut(_:))
    {
        return false
    }
    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

But I can't remove lookup & Share

[image]

Can anyone please suggest me how to remove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Make sure 
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(select(_:))
    {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: if action == #selector(select(_:))
        {
            return true
        }else{ false }

Comment: use this condition

Comment: Please user proper format to make every one understood.

Answer (score 10):

If you really don't want to allow any actions, why do you check for each of them specifically? Just return false in your method. Otherwise, you can place a breakpoint and see what you're getting called with for "action" and add another validation for it

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    print("BlahTextView::canPerformAction: \(action)")
    return false
}
```

And the result, with the 2 you want removed highlighted:

> BlahTextView::canPerformAction: cut:
>   BlahTextView::canPerformAction: copy:
>   BlahTextView::canPerformAction: select:
>   BlahTextView::canPerformAction: selectAll:
>   BlahTextView::canPerformAction: paste:
>   BlahTextView::canPerformAction: delete:
>   BlahTextView::canPerformAction: _promptForReplace:
>   BlahTextView::canPerformAction: _transliterateChinese:
>   BlahTextView::canPerformAction: _showTextStyleOptions:
>   BlahTextView::canPerformAction: **_lookup**:
>   BlahTextView::canPerformAction: _define:
>   BlahTextView::canPerformAction: _addShortcut:
>   BlahTextView::canPerformAction: _accessibilitySpeak:
>   BlahTextView::canPerformAction: _accessibilitySpeakLanguageSelection:
>   BlahTextView::canPerformAction: _accessibilityPauseSpeaking:
>   BlahTextView::canPerformAction: **_share**:
>   BlahTextView::canPerformAction: makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:
>   BlahTextView::canPerformAction: makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:

And then you can do:

```
override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(copy(_:)) ||
        action == #selector(paste(_:)) ||
        action == #selector(select(_:)) ||
        action == #selector(selectAll(_:)) ||
        action == #selector(cut(_:)) ||
        action == Selector(("_lookup:")) ||
        action == Selector(("_share:")) ||
        action == Selector(("_define:"))
    {
        return false
    }
    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

The alternate syntax is required because those methods are not publicly declared and you'll get a compiler error if you use #selector(*share(*:)) for example.

for lookup - please use ((_define:)) Thanks.

Comment: look up is not removed

Comment: Tried this too. Lookup is not removed. It explains in the docs that other components can say true which will override what is done here. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621105-canperformaction

Comment: For removing lookup, you need to remove (define) action == Selector(("_define:"))

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in comment of one answer that you want to just enabled `select` then why don't you compare `select` and return `true` for it and `false` in other case.

```
override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(select(_:)) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```